# ApacheDS enable SSL on embedded LDAP server

Tags: java, ssl, ldap, openldap, apacheds

Using ApacheDS 2.0 I have created embedded Ldap server. Example [here](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/directory/sandbox/kayyagari/embedded-sample-trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/directory/seserver/EmbeddedADSVerTrunk.java). **How can I enable ssl?** I did not find any method in LDAP API or DefaultDirectoryService class which enables SSL. I was able to configure the keystone and password though.

Java Code:

> ```
> server = new LdapServer();
> int serverPort = 10636;
> TcpTransport transports = new TcpTransport(serverPort);
> server.setTransports(transports);
>
> server.setKeystoreFile("foo/bar.jks");
> server.setCertificatePassword("changeit");
> server.loadKeyStore();
> server.setDirectoryService(service);
>
> System.out.println("SSL ? " + server.isEnableLdaps(transports)); //this prints false
>
> server.start();
> ```

Answer (score 0):

We need to enable in transport.

> ```
> TcpTransport transports = new TcpTransport(serverPort);
> transports.setEnableSSL(true);
> ```

Comment: Looks like this is not enough. I am seeing ssl handshake issue. But could be related to certificate I am using.

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common